# Unable to pass a list as an argument to a function? How can I pass the list without getting an error?

Tags: r, purrr, httr, jsonlite

I have the following function

```
my_func <- function(sport,
                eventId = eventids,
                apiKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                regions = "us",
                markets = "alternate_spreads",
                odds_format = "american",
                date_format = "iso"){
    
    base_url = glue::glue("https://xxx.xxx-xxx- 
xxx.xxx/xx/xxxxxx/{sport}/xxxxxx/{eventId}/odds")
    
    query_params <- list(apiKey = apiKey,
                         sport = sport,
                         eventId = eventId,
                         regions = regions, 
                         markets = markets,
                         oddsFormat = odds_format,
                         dateFormat = date_format)
    
    endpoint <- httr::modify_url(base_url, query = query_params)
    
    resp <- fromJSON(endpoint) %>% 
            as_tibble(validate = F) %>% 
            unnest(cols = bookmakers) %>% 
            rename("bookmaker_key" = "key") %>% 
            unnest(cols = markets) %>% 
            unnest(cols = outcomes)
    
    return(resp)
}
```

I am trying pass the following list of eventids as an argument

```
eventids <- followinglist

A tibble: 2 × 1
   id                              
   <chr>                           
 1 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxadaf06d2660af34
 2 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxa67aa5a4bce731a0
```

When I execute the following syntax

```
my_func('basketball')
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in open.connection(con, "rb") : 
cannot open the connection to 'https://xxx.xxx-xxxx-xx/sports/basketball/events/truncated?
In addition: Warning message:
In open.connection(con, "rb") :
cannot open URL 'https://xxx.xxx-xxxx-xx/sports/basketball/events/truncated?

HTTP status was '422 Unknown Error'
```

I have also tried using the following format of eventids

```
eventids <- c("xxxxxxxxxxxxxx57adaf06d2660af34", "xxxxxxxxxxx7aa5a4bce731a0")
```

and get the following error when running running the function

```
Error in parse_url(url) : length(url) == 1 is not TRUE
```

I found another post that suggested using

```
eventids1 = paste(eventids, collapse = ",")
```

However, I get the same error as above

```
Error in open.connection(con, "rb") : 
cannot open the connection to 'https://xxx.xxx-xxxx - this has been truncated
```

I have also tried using the following

```
map(eventids, my_func)
```

but get the following error

```
Error in `map()`:
ℹ In index: 1.
Caused by error in `parse_url()`:
! length(url) == 1 is not TRUE
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

I know the function works because if I pass a single eventid, I get a response and data

```
my_func('basketball', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx4bce731a0')
```

The API only allows a single eventid to be passed at a time which is my reason for wanting to pass a list of eventids.  How can I query the API by passing a list and having the responses written to a tibble?  Thank you in advance.

I tried running the following

```
map(eventids, ~my_func(sport = "basketball", eventId = .x))
```

but got the following error.

```
Error in `map()`:
ℹ In index: 1.
ℹ With name: id.
Caused by error in `parse_url()`:
! length(url) == 1 is not TRUE
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
> rlang::last_error()
<error/purrr_error_indexed>
Error in `map()`:
ℹ In index: 1.
ℹ With name: id.
Caused by error in `parse_url()`:
! length(url) == 1 is not TRUE
---
Backtrace:
1. purrr::map(eventids, ~my_func(sport = "basketball_nba", eventId = 
.x))
2. purrr:::map_("list", .x, .f, ..., .progress = .progress)
6. global .f(.x[[i]], ...)
7. global my_func(sport = "basketball_nba", eventId = .x)
8. httr::modify_url(base_url, query = query_params)
9. httr::parse_url(url)
10. base::stopifnot(length(url) == 1)
11. base::stop(simpleError(msg, call = if (p <- sys.parent(1L)) 
sys.call(p)))
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see the full context.
> rlang::last_trace()
<error/purrr_error_indexed>
Error in `map()`:
ℹ In index: 1.
ℹ With name: id.
Caused by error in `parse_url()`:
! length(url) == 1 is not TRUE
---
Backtrace:
 ▆
1. ├─purrr::map(eventids, ~my_func(sport = "basketball_nba", eventId = 
.x))
2. │ └─purrr:::map_("list", .x, .f, ..., .progress = .progress)
3. │   ├─purrr:::with_indexed_errors(...)
4. │   │ └─base::withCallingHandlers(...)
5. │   ├─purrr:::call_with_cleanup(...)
6. │   └─global .f(.x[[i]], ...)
7. │     └─global my_func(sport = "basketball_nba", eventId = .x)
8. │       └─httr::modify_url(base_url, query = query_params)
9. │         └─httr::parse_url(url)
10. │           └─base::stopifnot(length(url) == 1)
11. │             └─base::stop(simpleError(msg, call = if (p <- 
sys.parent(1L)) sys.call(p)))
12. └─purrr (local) `<fn>`(`<smplErrr>`)
13.   └─cli::cli_abort(...)
14.     └─rlang::abort(...)
```

Comment: have you checked whether the ids provided in the vector work individually?

Comment: There are currently 13 eventids.  I checked 2 of them and yes they return data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems like your function can only accept a single scalar eventid as its argument, but you are trying to pass a vector of eventids.
Moreover, you should provide the arguments for which there are no defaults, for every call to `my_func`. These are `sport` and `eventId`.

You may want to loop through the eventids vector like this:

```
map(eventids, ~my_func(sport = "basketball", eventId = .x))
```

Comment: Thanks @ GuedesBF.  I am specifying the "sport" manually when executing the command as well as specifying the "eventid" vector.  I tried your suggestion but get the same error.  I will update my original post with the new error as it is too long to fit in this comment.

Comment: Any ideas?  Are you aware of any other forums where I might ask this question?

Answer (score 0):

After using the following syntax

```
eventids <- nba_h2h %>% 
    distinct(id) %>% 
    pull()
```

and converting from class tibble to class "character" I was able to execute the following

```
map(event_ids, ~my_func(sport = "basketball_nba", eventId = .x)) 
%>% bind_rows()
```

Thanks for the help and guidance!

Comment: Happy you found the way. A tip: if you replace `map` with `map_dfr`, i think you no longer need to call `bind_rows` afterwards